# How to correctly copy Boost arrays in ROS callbacks?

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, callback, ros

I am relatively new to C++ (I am experienced in C and embedded C), some C++ concepts are still difficult to wrap my head around.

I am trying to copy boost array from a ROS callback. For those who are not familiar with ROS, the callback in my program (node) passes a reference to an object from the ROS messaging system.

The callback's declaration is: `void callback(const boost::shared_ptr<std_msgs::uint8_t>&);`

Let's say I have two references that I want to copy from the callback, one of `bool foo` and another one `boost::array<uint8_t, 8UL> bar`.

Now, this is how I can copy the bool type:

```
bool x;

void callback(const boost::shared_ptr<std_msgs::uint8_t>& msg) {
    x = msg->foo;
}
```

This works fine, copies the value into another variable before the object is destructed.

Now, I am not familiar with Boost at all. Boost's array public construct/copy/destruct is this ([reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost/array.html)):

```
template<typename U> array& operator=(const array<U, N>& other);

Effects:
std::copy(rhs.begin(),rhs.end(), begin())
```

Here's how I am trying to do to copy `bar` variable:

```
boost::array<uint8_t, 8UL> y;

void callback(const boost::shared_ptr<std_msgs::uint8_t>& msg) {
    std::copy(msg->bar.begin(), msg->bar.end() + 8, y.begin());
}
```

This again works fine, however is that the correct way of doing it? As far as I know `std::copy` function uses iterators, I don't exactly understand how this works (and if it's correct). I am familiar with `memcpy()`, could I use that instead, and if so, what would be the advantages?

EDIT: Also, if I did something like this:

```
boost::array<uint8_t, 8UL> y;

void callback(const boost::shared_ptr<std_msgs::uint8_t>& msg) {
    y = msg->bar;
}
```

Would that be copied or referenced?

Comment: 'Would that be copied or referenced?' Copied. It calls the assigment operator for the boost array which copies the elements. Note there is no way in C++ to copy a reference. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @john, thank you, that's really helpful. What about the correct way of copying?

Comment: Using the assignment operator is the correct way (in this case). Using `std::copy` comes to the same thing but is less idiomatic.

Comment: @john, after looking at that reference link I can now see what you mean (even though I am not very familiar with templates and OOP). If you put this in an answer I will give it a star, thank you!